# How do I escape '/' in xml attribute?

Tags: xml

Example:

```
   <ch="abc" xyz/abc.pqrst.bfg="12345" />
```

While doing the above I m getting the parsing exception after xyz.How do we escape '/' in the above example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That doesn't look like valid XML to me....

Comment: See *Name* in the [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name), and "The ASCII symbols and punctuation marks, along with a fairly large group of Unicode symbol characters, are excluded from names because they are more useful as delimiters"

Comment: Questions like this always make me wonder, what terrible XML examples are out there that are teaching such usage? _<ch="abc" ?_ - grizzly

Comment: Maybe it's imposed by an external system that sucks at compliance. Y'know, like Microsoft. Have you tried simply replacing it with `&#47;`?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets That's the spec for attributes which looks like a forward slash is OK. The element name is invalid, of course, I suspect its a misunderstanding about XML namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

First, your sample does not have a tag name (only attributes), hence is not a valid XML string. Let's assume you have instead:

```
<someTag ch="abc" xyz/abc.pqrst.bfg="12345" />
```

Then, "xyz/abc.pqrst.bfg" is not a valid attribute name according to the [XML specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name), as "/" is not a valid character for a name; and there are no escaping mecanism for these names either, per the same specifications.